# postgresql materialized view ERROR: a negative number raised to a non-integer power yields a complex result

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, postgresql-13

I have complex view with calculations but one line makes issue

```
ROUND((((latest_revenue::numeric/ oper_reve_3y_old::numeric) ^ (1/3::numeric)) -1::numeric)*100::numeric)
```

When I execute the query, calculation works fine, when I use it in view, all works well, but if I try to create materialized view with this statement, I get error

> " a negative number raised to a non-integer power yields a complex
> result"

is there any way how can I use this in materialized view? or is there some explanation why this does not work for materialized view only?

Comment: you're right, problem is with oper_reve_3y_old which contains negative number , but now I just dont understand why I can create normal view, but not materialized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get the same error if you query *the whole* view:

```
SELECT * FROM view_name;
```

You probably don't see the error when you use the view because you are using additional `WHERE` conditions that avoid the problematic values.

Remember that a view is just a named `SELECT` statement, so querying a view is not necessarily done by first calculating the whole view and then applying conditions. However, when you create a materialized view, all data from the view have to be selected.

Comment: Thanks, actually select * from view works without where same as select * from query...the reason is that dbeaver I use is querying by parts and those I see in result are not problematic. But can you explain me this behavior of postgres please?

Comment: I thought I had explained the behavior. Your client doesn't add a `WHERE` condition, but a `LIMIT` clause, which has the same effect: not all rows are calculated.

Comment: yes I understand that, but I dont understand why postgres cannot calculate this if calculator is able to do that...I am trying to find out root cause of this issue in postgres

Comment: Then your calculator can handle complex numbers. `numeric` or `double precision` cannot do that. Sure, you could define your own `complex` data type (or choose an existing extension) that implements such an operation.